# OpenCV can only detect the left profile of the faces?

Tags: c#, opencv

I am using haar cascade for profile face, but i have noticed that it only detects the left side of face not right. Am I worng? Or have i missed something? Any one has any idea about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also can't find why. I think the classifier was created using left profile of face. But you can flip the image horizontally, then do the detection.